# Adding and setting up a TableViewCell in a static TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have a static TableView which is actually an input form. This form has 5 sections, with each a different amount of cells:

```
let numberOfRowsAtSection:[Int] = [5,3,1,1,2]

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return numberOfRowsAtSection.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numberOfRowsAtSection[section]
}
```

In the third section I have one cell, with two labels, two textFields and one button in it. If the button is tapped I want to add another cell in this section, just like the first cell.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: *Adding* and *static* is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documenation says ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW27)):

> **Dynamic prototypes**. Design a prototype cell and then use it as the
>   template for other cells in the table. Use a dynamic prototype when
>   multiple cells in a table should use the same layout to display
>   information. Dynamic content is managed by the table view data source
>   (the table view controller) at runtime, with an arbitrary number of
>   cells.
>
> **Static cells**. Use static content to design the overall layout of the
>   table, including the total number of cells. A table view with static
>   content has a fixed set of cells that you can configure at design
>   time. You can also configure other static data elements such as
>   section headers. Use static cells when a table does not change its
>   layout, regardless of the specific information it displays.

Also, the same documentation says that a static table view should not implement any dataSource method.

So the answer to your question is either to implement a dynamic tableView, in which case `insertRow(at:with:)` (plus the `dataSource`methods) should do the work, or add the desired input in storyboard and hide it until the condition is hold.

Answer (score 1):

In the `IBAction` of your button, you just need to call `tableView.insertRows` to insert a new cell at the specified row.

```
@IBAction func addNewCell(){
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 2)], with: .none)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new .xib file with the layout of the cell that you'd like.

Then use UITableView's `register(_ nib: UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)` to register it to your static table view.

Then just use `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: String, for indexPath: IndexPath)` with the identifier of the cell and you're all set.